# Is there a simple proof for $\frac{2n}{3}$ is not an integer when $\frac{n}{3}$ is not an integer?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

Obviously if $\frac{n}{3}$ is an integer then $\dfrac{2n}{3}$ is an integer. But what if $\frac{n}{3}$ is not an integer? Can it be proven that $\dfrac{2n}{3}$ is not an integer (or, more specifically, an even multiple of 3) if $\frac{n}{3}$ is not an integer?

I feel that intuitively this must be true, but I am not a mathematician and my idle algebraic musings aren't helping me. Is there a quick, simple proof one way or the other?

[Sorry if this is mistagged.]

Comment: To be precise, you might want to include what $n$ is (probably an integer).

Comment: @wildildildlife: Yes, thanks. I mean *n* to be an integer.

Comment: If $n = \frac 32$, then $\frac{2n}{3}$ is an integer but $\frac n3$ isn't. So $n$ kinda has to be an integer for this problem to make any sense.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Simply notice that $\rm\displaystyle\ \frac{n}3 + \frac{2n}3 = n\in \mathbb Z\ \ $ thus $\rm\displaystyle\ \frac{n}3\in\mathbb Z \iff \frac{2n}3\in \mathbb Z.\,$ This works precisely because $\rm\mathbb Z$ is an additive *subgroup* of $\rm\:\mathbb Q,\:$ i.e. a subset closed under subtraction. For if $\rm\:S\:$ is a subgroup of a group and $\rm\ a+b\ = s \in S\ $ then $\rm\ a = b-s \in S\!\iff\! a+s = b\in S,\, $ so your property holds. Conversely if the property holds and $\rm\:a,b\in S\ $ then since $\rm\, (a-b)+b = a \in S\, $ the property implies that $\rm\: a-b\in S\:,\: $ so (nonempty) $\rm\:S\:$ is closed under subtraction, so $\rm\:S\:$ is a subgroup, by the subgroup test.

See also the below *complementary* form of the subgroup property [from my prior post.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11747/proof-that-dividing-irrational-number-by-an-irrational-number-can-result-in-an-in/11760#11760)

**Theorem**  $\  $ A nonempty subset $\rm\:S\:$ of abelian group $\rm\:G\:$
comprises a subgroup $\rm\iff\ S\ + \ \bar S\ =\ \bar S\ $ where  $\rm\: \bar S\:$ is the complement of $\rm\:S\:$ in $\rm\:G$

Instances of this are ubiquitous in concrete number systems, e.g.

> ```
>                                  transcendental 
>      algebraic * nonalgebraic  =  nonalgebraic  if  nonzero 
>       rational * irrrational   =   irrational   if  nonzero 
>           real *   nonreal     =    nonreal     if  nonzero 
>
>          even  +     odd       =      odd          additive example
>        integer + noninteger    =   noninteger
> ```

Comment: Thanks for this. Quite the beautiful (i.e. simple) answer I was looking for. Am I correct in interpreting the material after "hence" as meaning "n/3 is a member of the set of integers if and only if 2n/3 is a member of the set of integers"?

Comment: @Rob Yes, that's correct. As I mentioned later, it boils down to the property that the integers are a subset of the rationals closed under subtraction.

Answer (score 6):

if $2n/3$ were an integer, then $n/3 = 4n/3 - n = 2*(2n/3) - n$ would also be an integer.

Answer (score 5):

Contradiction.

Assume by contradiction that 2n/3 is an integer m and deduce from here that 3 divides n.

Hint: think about the prime factorisation of n.

Answer (score 4):

Every integer $n$ can be written in the form $n = 3a + b$ where $a$ is an integer and $b$ is one of $0,1,2$. Now $n/3$ is an integer exactly when $b = 0$. Consider the representation of $2n$. There are three cases.

If $b = 0$ then $2n = 3(2a)$.

If $b = 1$ then $2n = 3(2a) + 2$.

If $b = 2$ then $2n = 3(2a+1) + 1$ since $4 = 3 + 1$.

So $2n/3$ is an integer only if $b = 0$, i.e. only if $n/3$ is an integer. And vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

Another way, is $\frac{2n}{3}$ is an integer iff $3\mid 2n$, but $3$ being prime implies that $3\mid 2$ or $3\mid n$, as the first cannot be, then $3\mid n$, and $3\mid n$ iff $\frac{n}{3}$ in an integer. See [Euclid's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma), also note that there´s no use of the prime factorization.

Answer (score 1):

If (n/3) is not an integer, then n is not divisible by 3.  If n is not divisible by 3, then (2*n) is not divisible by 3.  Therefore, if (n/3) is not an integer, neither is ((2*n)/3).

Answer (score 0):

If $2n/3$ is an integer it is either odd or even. If it is even then $n/3$ is also an integer. If it is odd then so is $3\cdot (2n/3)=2n$, but this is clearly even.