# If every element of $R$ is irreducible or a unit, then $R$ is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

This is not for homework, but I seem to be stuck a would like a **hint** please.  The question asks

> If every nonzero element of an integral domain $R$ is either a unit or irreducible, then $R$ is a field.

The question looks non-threatening, and I'm surely missing something obvious.  I started by choosing some nonzero $r \in R$.  If $r$ is a unit then there is nothing to prove.  If $r$ is irreducible, however, I don't immediately see how to conclude that $r$ is invertible.  Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What can you say about $r^2$?

Comment: Hint: [Can non-units be multiplied together to form units?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/147491/242) $\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: If $r$ is irreducible, then what can be said about $r^2$? What does this imply about $r$?

Comment: OK, now I would like someone to explain this to *me*!  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, it's certainly not true that $r^2$ is irreducible, since it can be written as $r\cdot r,$ and neither of $r$ or $r$ (silly, I know, but true) is a unit. Furthermore, since $r\ne 0$ and $R$ is an integral domain, then $r^2\ne 0,$ and so $r^2$ is a unit by hypothesis. Hence, there is some $u\in R$ such that $r^2\cdot u=1,$ but then $r\cdot u\in R,$ and $r\cdot(r\cdot u)=r^2\cdot u=1,$ and so $r$ is a unit, giving us the desired contradiction.

Comment: To Cameron Buie:  "neither $r$ nor $r$ is a unit" . . . that *is* good!  Thank you very much, Professor Buie!