# Question about a hint in the question: If every nonzero element of $R$ (integral domain) is either irreducible or a unit, prove that $R$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra

*Background:*

**Exercise 21:**  If every nonzero element of $R$ (integral domain) is either irreducible or a unit, prove that $R$ is a field.

*Questions:*

In the above exercise, the hint suggested that the reader should consider for every nonzero $a\in R,$ to consider $a^2\in R.$ I know that $a^2\neq 0.$  But why is it i can assume that $a^2\cdot u=1$ for some unit $u\in R$?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hint: [Can non-units be multiplied together to form units?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/147491/242) $\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque thank you for the reference post.  I have a feeling irreducible elements and associates are not as simple as they appear.  At least not to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a$ is a unit, then obviously $a^2$ is also a unit.

If $a$ is not a unit, then $a^2$ is clearly reducible, and therefore by the definition of our ring, a unit.

Comment: if $a$ is not a unit, why does it automatically make it irreducible?

Comment: @Seth The problem statement says "every nonzero element of $R$ (integral domain) is either irreducible or a unit". But I deleted that part, as the irreducibility of $a$ is actually irrelevant.

Comment: oh kk.  Sorry my bad.  Sometimes these little details by passes my brain from some reasons.

Comment: @Seth It happens to everyone from time to time. Case in point: I made a comment on this site just yesterday asking about a detail in an answer I couldn't figure out, because I had forgotten the main premise of the whole solution, in much the same way.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).
It's best for site health to delete this answer (which also minimizes community time wasted on dupe processing.)

Comment: @Arthur thank you for that.