# proof for members of ideals

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

If $I$ is an ideal, could you show that if $ x\in I$ and $y\notin$ I, then $x+y \notin I$? It seems like an intuitively obvious statement and yet my rigor is failing me. So if you could show me all the steps of the proof that would be much appreciated.

Comment: If $x + y \in I$ and $x\in I$ then $x + y - x = y \in I$ contradiction.

Comment: This is really a fact about groups.

Comment: @Tobias Perhaps you could write that as an answer so the question can be marked as answered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume for the sake of contradiction that $x\in I$, $y\not\in I$ and $x+y\in I$. Since $I$ is a subgroup of the additive group of the ring, we have that $y = (x+y) - x \in I$ which is a contradiction. As mentioned by Dylan Moreland, this is a general fact about subgroups of any group.

Answer (score 1):

Another way which I find useful in dealing with things like this: Suppose that $x \in I$, $y \notin I$ but $x + y \in I$. Then saying that $x + y \in I$ ***implies that*** $x + y = m$ ***for some*** $ m \in I$. Rearrange to write $y = x - m$. Now $x \in I$ and $m \in I$. Since $I$ is an ideal and $m \in I$ we must have

$$(-1)\cdot m = -m$$

being in $I$. Furthermore $I$ being closed under addition means that $x + (-m) = x - m \in I$. However recall $y = x-m$ so this means $y \in I$ which contradicts the assumption that $y \notin I$.

$\hspace{6in}$ Q.E.D.

Answer (score 1):

This is a special case of the following *complementary* view of a subgroup.

**Theorem** $\ $ Let $\rm\,G\,$ be a nonempty subset of an abelian group $\rm\,H,\,$ with complement set $\rm\,\bar G = H\backslash G.\,$
Then $\rm\,G\,$ is a subgroup of $\rm\,H\iff G + \bar G\, =\, \bar G. $

**Proof**  $\ $ $\rm\,G\,$ is a subgroup of $\rm\,H\iff G\,$ is closed under subtraction, so, complementing

$\begin{eqnarray} & &\ \ \rm G\text{ is a subgroup of }\, H\  fails\\
&\iff&\ \rm\ G\ -\ G\ \subseteq\, G\,\ \ fails\\
&\iff&\ \rm\ g_1\, -\ g_2 =\,\ \bar g\ \ \ for\ some\ \ g_1,g_2\in G,\ \ \bar g\in \bar G\\
&\iff&\ \rm\ g_2\, +\ \bar g\ \ =\,\ g_1\  for\ some\ \ g_1,g_2\in G,\ \ \bar g\in \bar G\\
&\iff&\ \rm\ G\ +\ \bar G\ \subseteq\ \bar G\ \ fails\qquad\ {\bf QED}
\end{eqnarray}$

Instances of this are ubiquitous in concrete number systems, e.g. below. For many further examples see some of my [prior posts here.](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Amath.stackexchange.com+dubuque+complementary+subgroup)

[image]