# Finding square roots of an unknown

Tags: roots

$p$ and $q$ are rational numbers, find the values of p and q given that
$2p = q \sqrt {76} + \sqrt {19}$

attempt:
$$2p = 2q \sqrt{19} + \sqrt{19}$$
$$2p = \sqrt{19}(2q+1) $$

How to continue or how should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Observe that the left side is rational, but the right side will be irrational unless one of the numbers is zero. This comes from the [fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45104/prove-that-the-product-of-a-non-zero-rational-and-irrational-number-is-irrationa) that the product of an irrational number and a nonzero rational number is always irrational.

Thus one of the brackets on the RHS must be zero, which implies $2q + 1  =0$. So we must have $p = 0, q = -\frac{1}{2}$.