# Taking derivative in different ways produce different functions

Tags: calculus, limits

Consider,

$$ f(x) = \frac{x^{n+1} - 1}{x-1}$$

If I took derivative using quotient rule,

$$ f'(x) = \frac{ (n+1)x^{n} (x-1) - (x^{n+1} -1) } { (x-1)^2}$$

Now,

$$ \lim_{x \to 1} f'(x) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

But, suppose I took derivative using product rule,

$$ f'(x) =( ( x^{n+1} -1) (x-1)^{-1})' =  (n+1)x^n(x-1)^{-1} -(x-1)^{-2} (x^{n+1} -1)$$

Now, for this function if I take limit by distributing over the sum of functions, then the limit is undefined for one of them,

$$ f'(x) = \lim_{x \to 1}(n+1)x^n(x-1)^{-1} -(x-1)^{-2} (x^{n+1} -1)$$

More particularly, this limit is undefined $$ \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{ x^n}{ (x-1)}$$

So, am I missing something is the derivative of a function different based on how exactly you take the derivative of it? I mean, if both functions are actually equivalent they should have the same limits.

Edit: Why does the limit only become defined when I do algebraic manipulations? I know that when I manipulate the expression, I am indeed changing the function.

Edit: I unaccepted the answer because I saw this [stack](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41888/lim-a-b-when-limb-does-not-exist?noredirect=1&lq=1) which says that for limit of a sum to exist, then the sum of limits must exist. and, the top answer says otherwise.

Comment: 1) How did you get $\lim f'(x) =1$? 2) If $a_n$ and $b_n$ don't have a limit it is possible that $a_n-b_n$ has a finite limit.

Comment: The two functions you get are equal

Comment: I fixed the typo @Ravi Rama Murthy

Answer (score 2):

Note $$f(x) = 1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^n,$$ so that $$f'(x) = 1 + 2x + 3x^2 + \cdots + nx^{n-1}$$ and $$f'(1) = 1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$

It is worth noting that although the above only applies for positive integer $n$, the result $f'(1) = n(n+1)/2$ is true for all real $n$.

Your calculation with the quotient rule is correct, but it is not clear how you evaluated the limit.

The product rule yields an equivalent expression for $f'(x)$ as in your quotient rule calculation.  This is not difficult to see once you factor the term $(x-1)^{-2}$.  It should be noted that evaluating the limit of each term separately is incorrect, because *both* terms are indeterminate.  It is only when you consider them together that the limit is defined.

For instance:  $$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) + g(x) \ne \lim_{x \to a} f(x) + \lim_{x \to a} g(x)$$ if the individual limits on the RHS do not exist.  You can construct a trivial example with $f(x) = -g(x) = 1/x$, and $a = 0$.  In your case, you are under the mistaken impression that $$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x^{n+1}-1}{(x-1)^2}$$ exists.  I do not know why you think it does.

Comment: Pl check the edit I have made

Comment: Oh I think  I get it now

Comment: So if I understood right, I have to sum up the functions before the limti?

Answer (score 0):

We can rearrange your second result into the first result:
$$(n+1)x^n(x-1)^{-1}-(x-1)^{-2}(x^{n+1}-1)=\frac{(n+1)x^n}{x-1}-\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{(x-1)^2}=\frac{(n+1)x^n(x-1)-(x^{n+1}-1)}{(x-1)^2}$$

Comment: Pl check the edit I have made

Answer (score 0):

The concise answer to this is that limit is not distributive unless each limit inside the brackets is well defined.

$$ \lim_{x \to a} [ f(x) + g(x) ] =  \lim_{x \to a} f(x) + \lim_{x \to a} g(x)$$

iff $ \lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ and $ \lim_{x \to a} g(x)$ is already well defined.