# Is product of algebraic and transcendental number transcendental?

Tags: transcendental-numbers

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{A}$, and  $\gamma \in \mathbb{T}$.
 I know  that the reciprocal of a transcendental number is transcendental.

**Question:**

> Is  $\alpha\cdot \gamma \in \mathbb{T}$?

Comment: This works for many "number systems". See [this answer,](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/878098/242) for a general viewpoint.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks Bill Dubuque, It is excellent reference.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- No if $\alpha=0$ (because then you get $0$ which is algebraic)
- Yes if $\alpha \neq 0$ (because if $\alpha \gamma$ is algebraic, then also $\alpha^{-1} \alpha \gamma = \gamma$ would be algebraic)