# Is $\ln\sqrt{2}$ irrational?

Tags: logarithms, irrational-numbers

I know that the natural log of any positive algebraic number is transcendental, as a consequence of the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem, but what about the natural log of the square root of two (which is irrational).

Is this rational or irrational?

Comment: $\sqrt2$ is algebraic: it is the root of $x^2-2=0$

Comment: $\ln 1=0$.${}{}$

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not only is $\ln(\sqrt{2})$ irrational, but it's also transcendental!

Proof: $$\Large \ln(\sqrt{2})=\ln(2^{1/2})=\frac{1}{2} \underbrace{\ln(2)}_{\in \mathbb{T}}$$ which is transcendental. $\square$

To see why the product of a transcendental number and a non-zero algebraic number is transcendental, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/900758/is-product-of-algebraic-and-transcendental-number-transcendental) .

---

For reference, $\mathbb{T}$ is the set of transcendental numbers.

Comment: How do they know that $\log(2)$ is transcendental? Because $2$ is a positive algebraic number. However, $\sqrt2$ is also a positive algebraic number.

Comment: @robjohn Ah, yes. I suppose I could have mentioned that $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{A},$ but it seems you've beaten me to it.

Answer (score 4):

If you already know that the log of a positive algebraic number is transcendental, then all you need to realize is that $\sqrt2$ is a positive algebraic number. $\sqrt2$ is a root of $x^2-2=0$.

Therefore, $\log(\sqrt2)$ is transcendental $\implies$ $\log(\sqrt2)$ is irrational.

Answer (score 0):

IRRATIONAL

because $\sqrt{2} = 2^{1/2}$ and hence $\ln(\sqrt{2} )= 1/2 \ln(2)=$ an irrational number

Answer (score 0):

Think that $\log\sqrt2=\frac12\log2$ !