# Why is $\{0, 2\}$ a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

I feel like this should be obvious but why is $\{0, 2\}$ a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_4$? So, $\langle 2\rangle=\{0,2\}$. Shouldn't this set contain the inverse ($-2$)? Or does it have to do with the fact that $(-2)(-2)=4=0$? Please advise.

Comment: What is the difference between $2$ and "$-2$"?  Recall, the minus sign merely means "*the additive inverse of*" which does not necessarily need to appear in other representations of the element.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your mathematical expressions.

Comment: As for "*does it have to do with the fact that $(-2)(-2)=4=0$*"  No, it doesn't.  It has to do with the fact that $2 + 2 = 0$.  Addition is what is important here, not multiplication.  You will find that the additive inverse of $0$ is $0$, the additive inverse of $1$ (*which you might when convenient decide to notate as $-1$*) is equal to $3$, the additive inverse of $2$ (*which you might when convenient decide to notate as $-2$*) is equal to $2$, and so on...

Comment: There's a problem with the title of the question. 2 is not a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_4$, it's an element. I guess you mean the subgroup generated by 2.

Comment: OK, I get it. Thanks for all the input. Much appreciated! Just what I was looking for @JMoravitz

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Thanks for the info @Shaun

Comment: I edited the question title to replace $\langle 2\rangle$ with $\{0, 2\}$, as this is what the question is asking. Also, $\langle 2\rangle$ is *by definition* a subgroup; it is the smallest subgroup containing $2$, so the original 3rd-party edit made no sense.

Comment: It's clearly a subgroup by the [Subgroup Test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/878098/242) which, as I explain there, we've known implicitly since grade school. You might find it helpful to view your question from this perspective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\langle 2\rangle = \{0, 2\}$ is a subgroup of the group $\mathbb Z_4 = \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$ under *modular arithmetic*, modulo $4$.

The identity of this group is $0$, and because $2+2 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$, it has order two, and hence $2$ generates a group (subgroup) of order 2.  In fact, the additive inverse of $2$ is $2$.

That is, $\langle 2 \rangle = \{0, 2\} \leq \{0, 1, 2, 3\} = \mathbb Z_4$.

Comment: Good approach to teach!

Answer (score 6):

The elements of $\Bbb Z_4$ are not technically $0$, $1$, $2$  and $3$; rather, they are equivalence classes of integers with respect to the divisibility of their differences by $4$, like so: $$[a]_4:=\{b\in\Bbb Z: 4\mid a-b\}.$$ The operation of the group is defined by $[x]_4+_4[y]_4=[x+y]_4$.

Thus, since $4\mid (-2)+2=0$, we have $[-2]_4=[2]_4$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: No, it isn't, @amWhy.

Comment: But $-2\equiv 2\pmod{4}$.