# What type of subgroup or algebraic property is this?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider the set on nonzero-rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}^*= \mathbb{Q}-\{0\}$ as a subgroup of the nonzero real numbers $\mathbb{R}^*=\mathbb{R}-\{0\},$ where the group operation $\cdot$ is multiplication. As a subgroup, $\mathbb{Q}^*$ has the additional property that:

1. $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^* \forall y\in \mathbb{Q}^*(x\cdot y\in \mathbb{Q}^*\Rightarrow x\in \mathbb{Q}) $ .

Can you give me the name for subgroups obeying property (1) please?

(*edit*: previously I had listed an additional property which was incorrect, which I since deleted.)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will delete that (1).

Comment: Yes, I will ask again for semigroups.

Comment: Use `\mathbb{Q}` to get $\mathbb{Q}$, instead of $\mathcal{Q}$. Also `\mathbb{R}` for $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Viewed contrapositively, it's just the [complementary subgroup test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/878098/242)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property is "being a subgroup": **every** subgroup of a group has that property.

Let $G$ be a group; let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. If $x\in G$ and $y\in H$ are such that $xy\in H$, then $x\in H$. Indeed, $x=(xy)y^{-1}\in H$, since $H$ is closed under products and inverses; hence $y^{-1}\in H$, and $xy,y^{-1}\in H$ implies their product is in $H$.

It is also the case that $yx\in H$ implies $x\in H$.

As an alternative argument: if $xy\in H$, then $xH\cap H\neq\varnothing$, and therefore $xH=H$; but this holds if and only if $x\in H$.