# Does $a \mid b $ and $a \nmid c$ imply $a \nmid b+c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know that if $a \mid b$ and $a \mid c$ then $a \mid b+c$.
Which is easy to see since

$a \mid b \Leftrightarrow \exists k \in \mathbb{N} : a \cdot k=b$ and

$a \mid c \Leftrightarrow \exists n \in \mathbb{N}: a \cdot n=c$.

Thus $b+c=ak+an=a(n+k)$, which implies $a \mid c+b$.

But does $a \mid b$ and $a \nmid c$ imply $a \nmid (b+c)$?

I think that this is true, but I do not know how to proof this.

Comment: Yes. In short: $$a\mid b\implies (a\mid b+c\iff a\mid c)$$

Comment: Suppose $a | b+c$ and try to reach a contradiction.

Comment: Perhaps explicitly considering the remainder of $(b + c)$ when divided by $a$ will be a good approach.

Comment: Easier: Start with $a\mid b\iff a\mid -b.$ So $a\mid b+c$ and $a\mid b$ means $a\mid (b+c)+(-b)=c.$ But that assumes you are working in the integers. If you are working in the natural numbers, you'll have to prove it seperately.

Comment: $\!\bmod a\!:\ b\equiv 0,\, \color{#c00}{c\not\equiv 0}\,\Rightarrow\, b+c\equiv \color{#c00}{c\not\equiv 0}\,$ by basic congruence laws, cf. linked dupe. $\ \ $

Comment: This is a much more general principle: If $G$ is a group, $H$ is a subgroup, $h\in H$, and $g\in G\setminus H$, then $gh\in G\setminus H$. From this we see lots of examples: Your result with $G=\mathbb{Z}$ and $H=\{am:m\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. But also, the sum of a rational and an irrational is irrational, the product of an invertible $n\times n$ matrix and a non-invertible $n\times n$ matrix is non-invertible, if $V$ is  a vector space and $W$ is a subspace, then for $w\in W$ and $v\in V\setminus W$, $v+w\in V\setminus W$.

Comment: @jwhite That too is a dupe, see the [complementary subgroup test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/878098/242).

Comment: My comment was not to oppose vote to close as a duplication. Just to provide a potentially beneficial viewpoint, which I see you've already expounded nicely upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is using the more general (and very important, this will come up all the time!) fact that if $a \mid x$ and $a \mid y$, then $a \mid mx + ny$ for all $m, n \in \mathbb Z$, where something of the form $mx + ny$ is called an integer combination of $x$ and $y$ for future note. I'd suggest trying to prove this on your own using the definitions you gave, ask for help if you need though.

From there, if you assume for a contradiction that $a \mid b$ and $a \nmid c$, but $a \mid b + c$, then using the above, $a \mid b$ and $a \mid b + c$ imply $a \mid (-1)b + (b + c)$, that is, $a \mid c$, which is a contradiction, so you must have $a \nmid b + c$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: Apologies, I did not see the duplicate linked as I answered (I believe it was not linked yet, which is my fault for jumping the gun).

Comment: Of course basic questions like this have been answered many times over the past $13$ years. Please delay answering them so that they can be processed appropriately.